# snmpd on Beaglebone/Debian, reading file with source

Tags: linux, bash, snmp, beagleboneblack, snmpd

I have installed snmpd on a Beaglebone Black with Debian and everything works perfect so far, except one thing.

I have configured snmpd.conf for a pass-through

```
pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.45919 /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/snmp-20
```

Then snmp-20 is a batch script that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-n" ]
then
exit 0
fi

. /root/snmp.cfg

#sSerialNumber
if [ "$2" = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.45919.1.120.5" ]
then
echo 1.3.6.1.4.1.45919.1.120.5
echo string
echo $serial
exit 0
fi
```

In snmp.cfg it looks like this

```
serial=12345
```

I feel this is all pretty straight forward. Now when I run `/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/snmp-20` or just `/usr/local/bin/snmp-20` I get the expected output.

When I do the `snmpget -c public -v2c localhost  1.3.6.1.4.1.45919.1.120.5` it returns with "No such instance currently exists ..."

However when I comment the ./root/snmp.cfg the snmpget call is successful, so the calling parameters all work correctly.

It seems the script exits when the `source /root/snmp.cfg` command is called, but only when called by snmpget, not when called from the prompt.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add that everything worked fine on the BBB with Angstrom.

Comment: The problem was resolved. The access rights of the root folder were not sufficient to allow access to snmp.cfg - CLOSED.